# Tietze extension theorem for $X=Y=\mathbb{R}^\omega$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, descriptive-set-theory

The Tietze extension theorem says that if $X$ is a Polish space (even a normal space) and $Y=\mathbb{R}^n$, then a continuous function $f:C \rightarrow Y$ on a closed set $C \subseteq X$ can be extended to a continuous function $g:X \rightarrow Y$.

My questions are:

1. If we consider $X=Y=\mathbb{R}^\omega$, i.e. the countable product of $\mathbb{R}$ which is universal for Polish spaces, does the theorem still hold?
2. If not, do we have a counter-example?

Thanks!

Comment: A space $Y$ is AE(C) for a class of spaces C iff for all spaces $X$ in C and every continuous function $f: A \to Y$ defined on a closed subspace of $X$, $f$ has a continuous extension $\bar{f}: X \to Y$. It's called an *absolute extensor* for C. The proof by Paul below generalises to : if all $Y_i$ are AE(C) then $\prod_i Y_i$ also is. Often we want $Y$ which is AE(C) to be in C itself, so a Polish $Y$ for the class of Polish spaces (like $\Bbb R^n$ and $\Bbb R^\omega$ indeed are), but the result holds in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be any normal space. You know that the Tietze extension theorem is true for $Y = \mathbb R$.  Now let $f : C \to  \mathbb{R}^\omega$ be map defined on a closed $C \subset X$. Letting denote $p_n : \mathbb{R}^\omega \to \mathbb R$ the projection onto the factor with index $n$, all $p_nf : C \to \mathbb R$ are continuous and have a continuous extension $g_n : X \to \mathbb R$. The map $g : X \to  \mathbb{R}^\omega, g(x) = (g_n(x))$, is continuous by the universal property of the product. It is an extension of $f$.